# Tomcat shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: java, tomcat, xampp

I have been working on xampp tomcat server and I'm new for it. I configured it and starts the xampp tomcat. It works fine and I see all the ports I configured perfectly but after 3 minutes it shows me this error

```
"Error: Tomcat shutdown unexpectedly.
4:55:38 PM  [Tomcat]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
4:55:38 PM  [Tomcat]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
4:55:38 PM  [Tomcat]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
4:55:38 PM  [Tomcat]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
4:55:38 PM  [Tomcat]    If you need more help, copy and post this
4:55:38 PM  [Tomcat]    entire log window on the forums"
```

I opened the Catalina log to get more info and I noticed this java eror:

```
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:640)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:665)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8080
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:406)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:610)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:382)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:393)
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 2):

See :

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
```

The port that Tomcat is configured to use, is already in use by another application.

Either shutdown the other application, or edit your `server.xml` file to use another port (the default one is 8080).

Answer (score 2):

This is the cause:

> Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind :8080

It means the server is trying to bind to port `8080` but your machine already has something bound there. Make sure one of your other processes isn't taking up that port, or select another one (probably in `server.xml`) to use.

Answer (score 0):

This means your port (8080) for the Tomcat Server is currently utilized by another service. You can resolve this in two ways:

**Option 1: Change the Tomcat server port**

Step 1: Navigate to the server.xml; by either clicking on the "Config" button on your control panel or go to this directory C:\xampp\tomcat\conf.

Step 2: Ctrl + F to search for 8080 and change port 8080 to a higher number and save.

Step 3: Then try again.

**Option 2: Kill/Stop all processes using port 8080 and 8005.**

Step 1: Open CMD on your device (Windows: windows button + R, then type cmd and hit enter).

Step 2: Type this command "netstat -aon find str | 8080".

Step 3: Look for all processes running on these ports and identify their PIDs.

Step 4: Type this command "taskkill /PID 12345 /F" where 12345 is the identified PID.

Step 5: Repeat for other identified PIDS.

Step 6: Try to start the Tomcat Server again.